# If a die is rolled twice, $A = (\text{first roll} > \text{second roll})$, and $B = (\text{first roll} = 6)$, does $P(A \mid B) = P(B \mid A)$?

Tags: probability

The problem says that the experiment consist of throwing a die two times, and the output consist in (first throw, second throw).

We define $A=(\text{first roll} > \text{second roll} ), B=(\text{first roll} = 6)$.

And the question is to say if  $P(A|B)=P(B|A)$.

I did this:

$P(A \cap B)=5/36$

$P(A)=15/36$

$P(B)=1/6$

So I conclude that the statement is false. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is event $C$?  You talk about events $A$ (firstroll is larger than second) and event $B$ (first roll is a six), but you have not mentioned anything about $C$...  Is there maybe a typo in what you typed for your question?  $P(A\mid B) = P(B\mid \color{red}{C})$?

Comment: Hurry up with the improvement of your question. I´ve voted to close.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. the correct question is P(A|B)=P(B|A), and there is no C.

Comment: Why do you think you are doing something wrong?  You correctly found $P(B)=\frac{1}{6}$, and you also found correctly that $P(A)=\frac{15}{36}$.  Now... what is $P(A\mid B)$?  What is $P(B\mid A)$?  Are they equal?  Yes or no?  If yes, then great.  If no, that's also great.  The problem is likely worded to ask you for a yes or no (*with reasoning and work shown*) for whether or not $P(A\mid B)=P(B\mid A)$.

Comment: Thanks JMoravitz :). The reason why im thinking that im wrong is the main question says that i have to identify what sentence is true. The first sentence is this, and is false, and the second sentence says that there is a password that consist 3 numbers from 0 to 50 and says that there are $50^3$ posible combinations and i think that this is false too, because there are 51*50*50 combinations, so then what is the correct answer ?

Comment: The password question (which is unrelated) would in fact have $51^3$ possible combinations (as there are 51 choices for the first number, 51 choices for the second number, and 51 choices for the third number).  What is wrong with both of the sentences being false?  Did it tell you that exactly one of the sentences was true?  It doesn't sound like it.  It sounds like a series of problems, each of which could be true or could be false.

Comment: It is possible also that you are not writing down the exact wording correctly of some of the problems or of the instructions.  For example, if the passwords question was integers from $\color{red}{1}$ to $50$ (*instead of from $0$ to $50$).

Comment: It says that i have to choose sentence. Also forgot to say that the in the password question there is a restriction that says  that two consecutive numbers cant be equal. And the interval is all  {0,1,...,50}

Comment: Let us restrict attention to the question as stated. Your probability calculations are all correct, and lead to the conclusion that the two conditional probabilities are not equal.

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in the comments, your calculations are correct, as is your conclusion that the statement $P(A \mid B) = P(B \mid A)$ is false.